# Expected array in simple cycle

Tags: vba, excel

Please, could your find what is wrong? 
I have simple VBA makro but still Expected array.

```
Dim C_1 As Double 
Dim C_2 As Double

    For k = 1 To 6
        C_1(k) = 19
        C_2(k) = 11
    Next k

     For k = 7 To 11
        C_1(k) = 29
        C_2(k) = 19
    Next k
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare your variables as arrays. You need:

```
Dim C_1(1 to 11) As Double 
Dim C_2(1 to 11) As Double
```